# WPF ContentControl with ViewModel Binding won't change (MVVM Light)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm currently trying to get navigation in my WPF Application working with the Messenger from the MVVM Light Toolkit (Also using the Locator and SimpleIoC).

My MainWindow has a ContentControl with simple Binding..

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>
```

..in the MainViewModel with the Messenger

```
    private ViewModelBase _currentPageViewModel;
    private readonly LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;
    private readonly RegisterViewModel _registerViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        RegisterMessenger();

        _loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        _registerViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();

        _currentPageViewModel = _loginViewModel;
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentPageViewModel; }
        set { Set(ref _currentPageViewModel, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterMessenger()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message.Notification);
            // Checks the actual content of the message.
            switch (message.Notification)
            {
                case "GoToLoginPage":
                    _currentPageViewModel = _loginViewModel;
                    break;
                case "GoToRegisterPage":
                    _currentPageViewModel = _registerViewModel;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

For example I bound a button with ICommand who sends the Messenger a String to switch the CurrentPageViewModel..

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("GoToRegisterPage"));
```

In order to tell which View it should display I set them in the App.xml like this..

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
     <view:LoginView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Yes, I did that with the RegisterViewModel too.. but when the Button is clicked, it sets the _currentPageViewModel trough the SwitchCase, but the ContentControl won't update the View..

I've found nothing what could help ('cause mostly stupidity, right?).
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the Property if you wanna set the viewmodel, otherwise NotifyPropertyChanged is NOT called and WPF dont changed anything..

```
public void RegisterMessenger()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (message) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message.Notification);
        // Checks the actual content of the message.
        switch (message.Notification)
        {
            case "GoToLoginPage":
                CurrentPageViewModel= _loginViewModel;
                break;
            case "GoToRegisterPage":
                CurrentPageViewModel= _registerViewModel;
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: dunno, wpf is always wrong datacontext or wrong binding expression or missing of NotifyPropertyChanged :)